# How do I calculate average in Observable<Double>?

Tags: rx-java2

I was thinking about using [RxJava2Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions), but for some reason these function don't return `Maybe/Single<Double>` which is a bit strange, IMO.

```
MathFlowable.averageDouble(Flowable.range(1, 10))
.test()
.assertResult(5.5);

Flowable.just(5, 1, 3, 2, 4)
.to(MathFlowable::min)
.test()
.assertResult(1);
```

Comment: I think I ported them before the decision was made in RxJava 2 RC3 to have certain operators return Maybe/Single/Completable. Just use `.singleOrError()` on them.